# NFS not active after boot

Tags: networking

After boot I have to do this to get nfs server running:
$ sudo service nfs-kernel-server reload
What is to be done to get nsf automatically running after boot.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add the `nfs-kernel-server` to autostart with

```
update-rc.d nfs-kernel-server enable
```